# RealmSwift notification block

Tags: ios, swift, realm, cllocationmanager

Application - using Realm(Swift) and LocationServices, making reminders (reminder = some region + some logic (region entered or region leaved) + notification). Added notification block to let LocationManager know about changes in reminders:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift
import CoreLocation

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
    var notificationToken: NotificationToken?
    let realm = RealmManager.sharedInstance
    let dataSource = RemindersDataSource()
    let locationManager = LocationManager.sharedInstance

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

        self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource
        self.notificationToken = self.dataSource.reminders.addNotificationBlock({ [weak self](changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            guard let tableView = self?.tableView else {
                return
            }
            switch changes {
            case .initial:
                tableView.reloadData()
                break
            case .update(let reminders, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                LocationManager.sharedInstance.refreshNotifications(with: reminders)
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }), with: .automatic)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}), with: .automatic)
                tableView.reloadRows(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }), with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()
                break
            case .error(let error):
                fatalError("\(error)")
                break
            }
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    deinit {
        self.locationManager.stopAllNotifications()
        self.notificationToken?.stop()
    }
}

extension MasterViewController {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let segueIdentifier = segue.identifier else {
            return
        }
        if (segueIdentifier == "editReminder") {
            let controller = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let reminder = self.dataSource.reminders[indexPath.row]
                controller.reminder = reminder
            }
        }
    }
}

extension MasterViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("Location updated, last is: \(locations.last!.coordinate)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
        guard let reminder = self.dataSource.realm.object(ofType: Reminder.self, forPrimaryKey: region.identifier) else {
            print("Strange, region is monitoring but reminder was not found. \(region)")
            print("Reminders: \(self.dataSource.realm.objects(Reminder.self))")
            return
        }
        if (reminder.inOut == .Out) {
            print("Event is invoked! Message: \(reminder.message)")
        } else {
            print("Event is not invoked! You watching for opposit event. Message: \(reminder.message)")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        guard let reminder = self.dataSource.realm.object(ofType: Reminder.self, forPrimaryKey: region.identifier) else {
            print("Strange, region is monitoring but reminder was not found. \(region)")
            print("Reminders: \(self.dataSource.realm.objects(Reminder.self))")
            return
        }
        if (reminder.inOut == .In) {
            print("Event is invoked! Message: \(reminder.message)")
        } else {
            print("Event is not invoked! You watching for opposit event. Message: \(reminder.message)")
        }
    }
}
```

After some random creating/editing reminders application crashes with error message "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xffff807c03b1904f)".
Well, I'm not quite sure, but that error appeared after I have added NotificationBlock.

I have checked all possible nil values, tried move updates in main queue, checked all unwrapped optionals - no success.

What it can be? What I am doing wrong? 
Any suggestions wold be appreciated...

Comment: You can set an Exception Breakpoint in Xcode to find the exact line that causes this problem.

Comment: Found the bug already (implemented different delegates to locationManager in different controllers), but thanks